# Error: No database selected need solution

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code i am a bit new php i am not sure why i am getting this issue.

Because i have checked that database is already connected.

Please let me know what i am doing wrong any help will be appreciate.

Thanks is advance.

code of mysql.php:

```
    <?php
    $db_name = "users";
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","mysql");
    mysqli_select_db($link,$db_name) or die("cannot connect to the database" . mysqli_error()); 
    ?>
```

code of check_user.php:

```
    <?php
    include "include/mysql.php";

    if (isset($_POST['submited'])) {
    $user_type = 1;
    $first_name = $_POST['fname'];
    $last_name = $_POST['lname'];
    $user_name = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $profile_image = $_FILES['profile_image'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $qualification = $_POST['qualification'];
    $short_discription = $_POST['qualification'];

    $check="SELECT * FROM user_information WHERE email = '".$email."'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($link,$check);
    $data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
    if($data[0] > 1) {
            echo "User Already in Exists<br/>";
    }
    else
    {

    $insert="INSERT INTO user_information (user_type, first_name, last_name, user_name, password, profile_image, gender, qualifications, comment, email)VALUES ('.$first_name.','.$last_name.','.$user_name.','.$email.','.$password.','.$profile_image.','.$gender.','.$qualification.','.$short_discription.')";


    if (!mysql_query($insert))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using incorrect concatenation for your values.

```
('.$first_name.','.$last_name.','.$user_name.','.$email.','.$password.','.$profile_image.','.$gender.','.$qualification.','.$short_discription.')
```

those must be like this, using `'".$variable."'` and not `'.$variable.'`

```
('".$first_name."','".$last_name."','".$user_name."','".$email."','".$password."','".$profile_image."','".$gender."','".$qualification."','".$short_discription."')
```

Then this code block:

```
if (!mysql_query($insert))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
```

You cannot mix `mysql_` functions with `mysqli_`, those different MySQL APIs do not intermix with each other.

Use:

```
if (!mysqli_query($link,$insert))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($link));
  }
```

In your DB connection, `mysqli_error()` requires a parameter be passed to it.

`mysqli_error($link)` as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php
`string mysqli_error ( mysqli $link )`

Also, your code is based on this conditional statement

```
if (isset($_POST['submited'])){...}
```

Make sure that your form is a POST method and that all contain a name attribute.

I noticed you are also using `$_FILES`. Make sure you have the correct enctype for it.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

I also noticed you may be storing passwords in plain text. If this is the case, it is highly discouraged.

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Plus, in regards to SQL injection,  [**use `mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Now, your question's title reads as *Error: No database selected*

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

States:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") 
        or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));
```

So, follow that convention.

Make sure your database "users" does in fact exist and is not a table, but a database.

Answer (score -1):

While this code can be made to work, there is not safety in your query and a SQL injection can be easily performed against your code by passing a `'; DELETE FROM <someTable>;` query.  It would be much better to use a prepared statement for this so that your query is properly sanitized.  Please look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password') or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

echo 'Connected successfully';

mysql_select_db('my_database') or die('Error');

$query = 'SELECT * FROM my_table';

$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```